# Interactive Map

Tags: html, image, dictionary, interactive

I have been trying to create a simple interactive map that would show the routes on top of images. This is my current code:

```
<div>
    <img src="img/routes1.jpg" width="846" height="503" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
        <area alt="" title="" href="img/routes2.gif" shape="rect" coords="300,240,108,88" />
    </map>
</div>
```

[image]

I am just trying to upload the routes on top of current map when I click on the image. Any help?

Comment: Please recreate your issue in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with externally hosted images, also what do you mean by "upload the routes on top of current map when clicked?"

Comment: Do you mean that you want the image specified in the `href` attribute of the `area` tag to replace the one shown ?

Comment: I saved the image in two different layers. I want to click on new york ans have the routes show up on top of maps.

Comment: Is the attached image the "***routes1.jpg***" ? And if so can you also show us the ***routes2.jpg*** ?

Comment: the attached image is the combination of the two layers. The final pieace that I want when you click on New York.

Comment: @ValentinaPani do the routes have transparency behind it?

Comment: yes. I saved it as a .gif. with no background

Comment: I just don't know what to use. if image hotspot is the way to go or some jquery that will upload that picture on top when I click on a certain spot. Thanks for all the help

Comment: @ValentinaPani what you can do is to display:none and have it "on top" of the map and then on click toggle a class to take off the display:none so it looks like it just overlaid ... that's just the 10 sec version

Answer (score 1):

Your approach with the map is a valid one.
Now you need to use javascript to handle the event of clicking on an `area` element and showing the relevant image.

The following should be a good start

```js
// keep references to the map and the overlay (route) element
var route = document.querySelector('#route'),
    map = document.querySelector('#Map');

// when an area is clicked
map.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel the default action of redirecting the browser to the image
  var target = e.target, // extract the actual area element that was clicked
      href = target.href; // and get the relevant value from the href property

  route.src = href; // assign the clicked route image to the overlay element

}, false);
```

```css
#map-system {
  position: relative;
}

/*
the #route is our overlay element
which gets absolutely positioned so it will fall on top of the map
*/
#route {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  /*the following line is to allow the mouse to click nodes underneath the visible route*/
  pointer-events: none; 
}

/*the following is to hide the route when no image is assigned to it*/
#route:not([src]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-system">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC6H0.jpg" width="846" height="503" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
  <img id="route">
  <!-- added this line to create the overlay item -->
  <map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Yqe.gif" shape="rect" coords="300,240,108,88" />
  </map>
</div>
```

Comment: @ValentinaPani keep in mind that you should probably use a .png file which allows partial transparency so the routes will not have those white pixels around them..